# file descriptor unable to read 1 byte

Tags: linux, io

I'm a beginner in Unix/Linux, just a question on file descriptor, my textbooks asks a question:

*In most Unix systems, typing ctrl-d indicates EOF on standard input. What
happens if you type ctrl-d to the program in Figure 12.6(just a program that use select()) to while it is blocked in the call to select?*

[image]

and the answer is :

**a descriptor is ready for reading if a request to read 1 byte from that descriptor would not block. If EOF becomes true on a descriptor, then the descriptor is ready for reading because the read operation will return immediately with a zero return code indicating EOF. Thus, typing ctrl-d causes the select function to return with descriptor 0 in the ready set.**

so my question:

why the file descriptor would not be able to read 1 byte before we press ctrl-d?

Comment: [Do not post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` blocks until there is something to read from at least one of the file descriptors in its fd_set. Prior to pressing CTRL-d there are no bytes to read. After pressing CTRL-d, stdin is closed, and when this happens the EOF byte is then available to read from stdin's buffer.

Comment: so under what circumstance that a request to read at least1 byte from that descriptor would block?

Comment: If you attempt to read from a file descriptor that does not have any bytes to read then it will block. If it has one or more bytes available to read, it will not block.

Comment: sorry I still don't get it, I must misunderstand some basic concepts. let's say a disk file has 20 bytes, and I just opened this file and about to read it, and it has a file descriptor, lets say its fd is 4.  so how can this file descriptor   does not have any bytes to read? could you give me a scenario with this example, thanks

Comment: Well in that case the file descriptor would correspond to a file with bytes available to read. Calling `select` on this file descriptor would NOT block because the file has bytes available to read. If the program then reads all of the bytes of the file, then it will reach EOF and no longer have any bytes available to read. Calling `select` after this would block forever. In your initial post the file descriptor refers to `stdin`. When the program starts, `stdin` has no bytes available to read until the user sends some input or closes `stdin` using ctrl-d.

Comment: but for stdin, if I don't type anything in the beginning just press ctrl-d, still there is no byte to read since I didn't type any character?

Comment: Ah, okay we are getting to the main part of your confusion. If the file descriptor is closed, or if we have reached the end of the file, reading from the file descriptor will always return EOF immediately without blocking. You can repeatedly read EOF forever. Thus `select` will not block because reading from the file descriptor will not block. I realize that I was incorrect in my last comment. I said that `select` would block forever if EOF is reached for the file descriptor. It's actually the opposite. `select` will NEVER block if it is used on a file descriptor that has reached EOF.

Comment: if the stdin is a terminal, if I just type something but don't press enter, the terminal is still not available to read until I press enter, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186399/discussion-between-akstat-and-amjad).